# Visual studio doesn't properly re-compile my changes, only a full clean / rebuild will result in the changes being compiled

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header-files

This occurs with every file in the c++ solution, after making changes it simply doesn't recompile the code properly. It will go through and recompile all the classes that include the header but no changes made to the header itself.

If I insert a breakpoint in the header I get this message:
[image]

And this error is removed once I perform a clean of the solution.

I have gone through some google searches and most results point to the issue being the build and run settings, however that doesn't seem to be the issue in my case. Regardless here are the settings I am using right now.
[image]

I have attempted stopping my extensions however even after disabling all of them the issue persisted. Any ideas?

This problem occurs on both Visual Studio 2017 and 2019, I have not checked 15 and below. I have tried disabling parallel compilation but it simply made the missing recompilation more common.

Comment: It would be good to specify exactly which version of visual studio

Comment: @M.M Edited to add the visual studio version and what I have tried.